# How to fix application showing generic app icon in OS X (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, mac, emacs, icons

This happens in one particular application (emacs for Mac) in a particular directory in my `/Applications` folder, for one particular account in my system. It used to show the correct icon before but now, the application shows this generic icon with paper in the background and brush, and 2 other tools forming the letter A. I have the application inside `/Applications/development` directory, and if I move it elsewhere, it works fine (shows the correct icon). I've already tried recreating the directory from scratch. I first gave the new directory a different name, but once I rename it back to `development`, the problem reoccurs. I've already tried rebuilding the Spotlight index, and removing the `Cache.db` file in `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder` directory, but nothing has worked so far. I have one other user in my MacBook and it doesn't experience the same problem. Any ideas what could be wrong in my system?

Comment: maybe try http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183166/how-do-i-restore-icons-in-finder